# If $f(f(f(x)))+f(x)=2$ for all $0≤x≤2$ then find $\int_0^2 f(x) dx$

Tags: calculus, functions, definite-integrals, functional-equations

> If $f(f(f(x)))+f(x)=2$ for all $0≤x≤2$, where $f(x)$ is a continuous function, then find $\int_0^2 f(x) dx$

Substitute $f(x)=2-t$ to get $$\begin{equation} f(f(2-t))=t \end{equation}$$
Take inverse on both sides and then integrate from $0$ to $2$
$$\int_0^2f(2-t)=\int_0^2f^{-1}(t)$$
On the other hand, substituting $f(f(x))=z$ in original equation gives $$f(z)=2-f^{-1}(z)$$
Putting the value of $f^{-1}(z)$ back we can solve for $\int_0^2 f(x) dx=2$

My solution gave me the right answer, but it's clearly wrong because 1) the range of $f(x)$ or $f(f(x))$ need not be a subset of the domain and 2) inverse of $f(x)$ may not exist. Also, the given data $0≤x≤2$ seems to be superfluous here. So what is the proper way of doing it?

Comment: This question looks like there are missing details: it is not specified the domain of $f$ (all we know is that the domain contains $[0;2]$), and the codomain as well. Maybe it is implicitly assumed that $f: [0;2] \to [0;2]$?

Comment: @Crostul that does seem to clear most of the trouble, so I guess you're right! One thread that would be left I suppose is checking for the validity of taking the inverse; will we have to assume an inverse exists? Or maybe there's some slightly different procedure that doesn't require taking an inverse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f$ is not invertible. Consider
$$f(f(f(x)))=2-f(x)$$
and suppose $f$ is increasing on $[0,2]$. Then
\begin{align*}
f(f(f(0)))<f(f(f(2))),\quad 2-f(0)>2-f(2)
\end{align*}
Conversly, suppose $f$ is decreasing on $[0,2]$. Then
\begin{align*}
f(f(f(0)))>f(f(f(2))),\quad 2-f(0)<2-f(2)
\end{align*}
It leads contradiction, so $f$ cannot increase or decrease on $[0,2]$. There's a trivial solution $f(x)=1$ to the functional equation that has
$$\int_0^2 f(x)dx=2$$
And I'm not sure that there exists other function satisfying the equation.

---

**Edit:**

We can prove $f(x)=1$. Suppose $f$ is a function defined in closed interval $[0,2]$. If $y$ is in range of $f$, then $2-y$ is also in range of $f$ by
$$f\circ f\circ f(x)=2-f(x).$$
Since continuous function maps closed interval to closed interval
$$f([0,2])=[1-p,1+p]$$
for $0\leq p$. Then suppose $0<p$ and consider $f:[1-p,1+p]\to[1-p,1+p]$. Then following holds.
$$f\circ f(x)=2-x$$
Note that $f$ is invertible since
$$f\circ f\circ f\circ f(x)=x\quad\Rightarrow\quad f^{-1}(x)=f\circ f\circ f(x)$$
We already verified that $f$ is not invertible, so $p=0$, that is $f$ is constant.

Comment: Wow that was really great! So ig I got the correct answer just by chance, even though I made an incorrect assumption? And also, just to be clear, you also assumed that $f: [0;2] \to [0;2]$ is given like @Crostul suggested in his comment, right?

Comment: @Amadeus Yeah, I assumed $f:[0,2]\to [0,2]$. I think that this assumption is necessary because the condition only holds on $[0,2]$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; btw, I noticed this only just now but isn't $f$ is invertible implied only for $x: [1-p,1+p]$? So it could still be not invertible on $x: [0,2]$ and not contradict our first result

Comment: @Amadeus The same argument can be applied to $[1-p,1+p]$ instead of $[0,2]$. Then $f:[1-p,1+p]\to [1-p,1+p]$ is not invertible and we get contradiction.

Comment: Oh yeah I got it now, thanks!

Comment: @pspsw I think the inequality should be $f(f(f(0)))\le f(f(f(2)))$, as $f(0)<f(2)$ may be strict , but $f(f(0))\le f(f(2))$ may not be, so does $f(f(f(0)))\le f(f(f(2))).$ It won't affect the correctness of the proof, anyway.

Comment: @DreaAR I don't think so. Invertible function is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. I assumed $f$ is defined on $[0,2]$, then both $f(0)$ and $f(2)$ are in $[0,2]$. $f(0)<f(2)$ leads $f(f(0))<f(f(2))$ where $f$ is strictly increasing.